# Unparseable date in java

Tags: java, android

I am try to compare to date.

below my java code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
     String currentDateString = sdf.format(new Date());
     System.out.println(currentDateString);

     Date currentDate = sdf.parse(currentDateString);
     System.out.println("date:"+currentDate.toString());

     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
     Date weatherDate = sdf.parse("2014-04-04");
     System.out.println("weatherDate:"+weatherDate);

     if(currentDate.equals(weatherDate)){
         System.out.println("true");
     }
```

Give me error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-04-04"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at DateTime.main(DateTime.java:43)
```

Please help me.

Comment: `"2014-04-04"` is not `"EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy"`

Comment: Do you understand that the string you pass into the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor is meant to represent the format of the data you then parse?

Comment: ok then how to convert 2014-04-04 to "EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy"

Answer (score 2):

`2014-04-04` & `EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy` does not match each other.

`2014-04-04` date string  exactly match with  `yyyy-MM-dd` date pattern.

Comment: ok then how to convert 2014-04-04 to "EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy"

Comment: Well in that case first you need to parse the date String with `yyyy-MM-dd` simple Date format and then `EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy` date pattern will help you format the date. You need two two formatter one to parse and 2nd to format again to string

Answer (score 0):

Your `SimpleDateFormat` parameter is completely wrong. Change it to match the format of the date you are providing.

Answer (score 0):

The date `"2014-04-04"` does not match the format you specified in the `SimpleDateFormat`.  The correct format would be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your this line

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

and also this line,

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy");
```

with

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```